# How to access values of dictionary when value contains another dictionary with multiple iterations on data?

Tags: python, json

my data is

```
 my_dict = {
     u'samosa': {
         u'shape': u'triangle',
         u'taste': None,
         u'random': None,
         u'salt': u'7.5.1'
     },
     u'idli': {
         u'color': u'red',
         u'eattime': u'134'
     },
     u'ridgegaurd': {},
     u'sambhar': {
         u'createdate': u'2016-05-12',
         u'end time': u'10655437'
     }
}
```

There are four keys `samosa`, `idli`, `ridgegaurd` and `sambhar`.

I don't want whole part of the values. I just want to get

```
value(shape) from samosa,
values(color and eattime) from idli
values(createdate and endtime) from sambhar
```

I want only the above values. I tried using dict but was not able to. Is it possible to write regular expressions for this?

Answer (score 2):

If the value of a dictionary entry is another dictionary, you can simply index it again.

```
my_dict[u'samosa'][u'shape']
my_dict[u'idli'][u'color'], my_dict[u'idli'][u'eattime']
my_dict[u'sambhar'][u'createdate'], my_dict[u'sambhar'][u'endtime']
```

Comment: thnks @Barmar sir. it worked. but what about if i want to write RE for that

Comment: That makes no sense. RE's process strings, not dictionaries.

Comment: thats ok. but what if the values i provided was a simple text file. i am asking it because i have made this text file into json format

Comment: Use a JSON parser and then process the dictionary.

Comment: If you try to parse JSON using your own regular expression, you're almost certain to run into problems with things like escape sequences. The JSON parser takes care of all this.

Comment: the solution u gave is working fine only for single typle.                          for key in my_dict.iteritems():
    heade= tt['samosa']['shape']
   #print tt['post']['event']
    #print tt['post']['ts']
    #print tt ['bottle']['timestamp']
    #print tt ['bottle']['game_id']
print heade
it is printing for the single key only, its not iterating over multiple keys

Comment: Your question didn't say anything about iterating. It asked how to access specific keys in each dictionary entry. If you have different needs, edit the question and show what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This function will recursively run through json and return a single dictionary with all the information, thus making it much easier to access your data:

```
def flatten(data):
    flattened = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flattened.update(flatten(v))
        else:
            flattened[k] = v
    return flattened
```

Comment: its not iterating over all the json, its showing only single instance of it. i mean i have like 1000 of lines of the json data which i have given

Comment: put it in a for loop bro.